# Actualizar campos de varias tablas en Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, orm, eloquent

Tengo una duda, como puedo realizar esta consulta en `laravel` usando `Eloquent`?

```
UPDATE Tabla1, Tabla2, Tabla
SET
Tabla1.estado = 1,
Tabla2.estado = 1,
Tabla3.estado = 1, 
WHERE 
Tabla1.estado = 0 
or 
Tabla2.estado = 0 
or 
Tabla3.estado = 0
```

No estoy muy segura de la consulta, pero lo que trato de hacer es actualizar de estado 3 tablas que tengan el `estado = 0`   por `estado = 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas. Sinceramente no creo que se pueda hacer esta consulta usando Eloquent. De lo que si estoy seguro es que si la divides puedes usar una expresión como esta:

```
// Tabla1, Tabla2 y Tabla3 son los modelos
Tabla1::where('estado', 0)->update(['estado' => 1]);
Tabla2::where('estado', 0)->update(['estado' => 1]);
Tabla3::where('estado', 0)->update(['estado' => 1]);
```

Esto está en la documentación de [Mass Update](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#updates)

Ahora hay mas opciones, que por cierto no son tan elegantes:

Usando Query Builder

```
DB::connection('mi_conexion')
    ->table(DB::raw('Tabla1, Tabla2, Tabla3'))
    ->where('Tabla1.estado', 0)
    ->orWhere('Tabla2.estado', 0)
    ->orWhere('Tabla3.estado', 0)
    ->update(['Tabla1.estado' => 1, 
              'Tabla2.estado' => 1, 
              'Tabla3.estado' => 1 ]);
```

Usando Raw Queries

```
DB::connection('mi_conexion')->statement('UPDATE Tabla1, Tabla2, Tabla3 SET Tabla1.estado = 1, Tabla2.estado = 1, Tabla3.estado = 1 WHERE Tabla1.estado = 0 or Tabla2.estado = 0 or Tabla3.estado = 0;');
```

Por cierto me parece muy extraño lo que intentas hacer, pero bueno..